# DIfferent types of properties in addproperty() function?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, vcf-vcard

I am using [Apache Jena](http://jena.apache.org/) and RDF to store emails. I am trying to create an RDF model with message id as URI and I am using [`addProperty()`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Resource.html#addProperty%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property,%20java.lang.String%29) function.

```
Resource addProperty(Property p,String o)

example:model.createResource(personURI).addProperty(VCARD.FN, fullName)
```

I want to know like we use VCARD class as property what are the other types that can be used ??
This may sound lame but I am very new to this and anything would be helpful.

Comment: You generally wouldn't want to use a class as a property.  You'd usually want to `addProperty( RDF.type, class )`, to indicate that something is a member of a particular class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,the best way is to create your own properties.Here's sample code for the email that I have created:`

```
//To define all the properties needed to make the rdf of the email

package email;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;


public class EMAILRDF {
    //Create a default model
    private static Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

//Subject of the mail
public static final Property SUBJECT = m.createProperty("SUB:" );
//Sender of the mail
public static final Property FROM = m.createProperty("FROM:" );
//Receiver of the mail
public static final Property TO  = m.createProperty("TO:" );
//Return path
public static final Property RETURN_PATH = m.createProperty("RETURNPATH:" );
//main contents of the mail
public static final Property CONTENT = m.createProperty("CONTENT:" );
//format of the mail
public static final Property FORMAT = m.createProperty("FORMAT:" );
//content type like html etc
public static final Property CONTENT_TYPE = m.createProperty("CONTENTTYPE:" );
//encoding in bits
public static final Property ENCODING = m.createProperty("ENCODING:" );
//date of the email
public static final Property DATE = m.createProperty("DATE:" );
```

}`

Comment: I like it. It looks clean :)

Answer (score 4):

The VCARD is a part of the `com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary` namespace and it implements the Property interface.  Here is a list of other vocabularies: ([source](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/vocabulary/package-summary.html))

- DB

  - Vocabulary for Database properties.
- DC_10

  - Dublin Core version 1.0 vocabulary.
- DC_11

  - Vocabulary definitions from file:vocabularies/dublin-core_11.xml
- DCTerms

  - Vocabulary definitions from vocabularies/dublin-core_terms.xml
- DCTypes

  - Vocabulary definitions from vocabularies/dublin-core_types.xml
- LocationMappingVocab

  - Vocabulary definitions from Vocabularies/location-mapping-rdfs.n3
- OntDocManagerVocab

  - Vocabulary definitions from file:vocabularies/ont-manager.rdf
- OntEventsVocab

  - Vocabulary definitions from file:vocabularies/ont-event.rdf
- OWL

  - Vocabulary definitions from file:vocabularies/owl.owl
- OWL2

  - OWL2 vocabulary.
- OWLResults

  - The vocabulary used by WebOnt to encode results of test runs.
- OWLTest

  - The vocabulary used by the WebOnt working group to define test manifests.
- RDF

  - The standard RDF vocabulary.
- RDF.Nodes

  - The same items of vocabulary, but at the Node level, parked inside a nested class so that there's a simple way to refer to them.
- RDFS

  - RDFS vocabulary items
- RDFS.Nodes

  - The RDFS vocabulary, expressed for the SPI layer in terms of .graph Nodes.
- RDFSyntax

  - This class includes fragment IDs from the RDF Syntax WD, to identify grammar rules etc.
- RDFTest

  - The vocabulary used by the RDFCore working group to define test manifests.
- ReasonerVocabulary

  - A collection of RDF terms used in driving or configuring some of the builtin reasoners.
- RSS

  - The standard RSS vocabulary.
- TestManifest

  - Vocabulary definitions from test-manifest.n3
- TestManifestX

  - Vocabulary definitions from test-manifest-x.n3
- VCARD

  - VCARD vocabulary class for namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#
- XSD

  - Defines Jena resources corresponding to the URIs for the XSD primitive datatypes which are known to Jena.

Comment: Thanks jason for your answer!! Actually I want to store emails as rdf ,so taking message id as URI(subject) and other entities like subject,to,from,etc as object I am trying to create a rdf model...can you tell me which property should I use for these different entities...

Comment: I'm not aware of a built in one for this, but if you look at the source you can see its really easy to define your own: https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/trunk/jena-core/src/main/java/com/hp/hpl/jena/vocabulary/DB.java

Comment: Maybe DC_11? https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/trunk/jena-core/src/main/java/com/hp/hpl/jena/vocabulary/DC_11.java